# How to deploy a Vite + React SSR application on Vercel?

Tags: express, vite, server-side-rendering, vercel

I am trying to deploy a Vite app on vercel which is using express to do SSR.

The express server runs successfully, vercel however doesn't deploy the built files (dist/server and dist/client, [see the Vite SSR Guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr#building-for-production))

I then changed the vercel build output configuration in hopes this will copy the files over:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "cache": ["./api/*", "./dist/server/*", "./dist/client/*"]
}
```

Now it doesn't output any files at all except a static middleware file.
[image]

### How can I configure vercel to output the folders *dist/server* and *dist/client* which are created during the build step?

Really not finding any information on this online